# Laravel 5, left join returns all items from right side of join

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join

I have 3 tables: "items", "faq" and a join table: "item_faq".  The item_faq table holds the relationship as well as an order column to help order faqs per item.

Currently in the database there are a total of 5 faqs.  There are a total of 9 rows in the item_faq table relating those 5 faqs to multiple items.

The context is that the admin can create/edit an item and select which faq's will be included, and their order.

On the item admin create/edit view I need to display all faqs and be able to checkbox which ones I want to include.

In my controller I am doing a left join like this:

```
$faqs = \App\Faq::leftJoin('item_faq', 'faq.id', '=', 'item_faq.faq_id')->get();
```

I am dd($faqs) to test what is returned and I am getting 9 objects.  This is where my issue is:  I need it to return the 5 faqs and if there is a item_faq that is related to this item and faq then the faq checkbox is checked.

**Schema:**

Item (40+ rows in db): id, other fields

Faq (there are 5 existing rows in db): id, question, answer, other fields

item_faq (9 rows in db): item_id, faq_id, order, date fields

Both Item and FAQ are in a many_to_many with eachother

**What I want to get back**

5 faq's and if there is a item_faq listing for the item and faq, that it would check that box.

Comment: Post your schema + data + expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if i get it:
You want the faq with their items (if it exists), right?
If that's what you want, you can use the `with` method like this:

```
$faqs = \App\Faq::with('items')->get();
```

On your Faq model you should have a relationship with Item

```
public method Items() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

Now you can get items from faqs with

```
foreach($faqs as $faq) {
    var_dump($faq->items);
}
```

EDITED:

I think you need to create a function to check every checkbox and see if it should be checked like this:
In your Faq model create this method:

```
public function hasItem($item) {
    return in_array($item, $this->items()->toArray());
}
```

In your blade for each item, you check if it's from FAQ. Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" id="{{ $item-id }}" {{ $faq->hasItem($item-id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Try this, please.

Comment: Ok this works.  I had to update slightly based on my setup but it works. The only thing it fails to do is order based on the order column in the join table.  This ties to the $faqs = \App\Faq::with('items')->get(); which works great but skips the order.  Any ideas on how to include the order?

Comment: Do you want to sort by Item column or Faq column?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like multiple item_faq rows has same faq_id, that is why it is joining all item faq rows with item_faq.

Only if it has one to one relationship, you can get exactly as many rows as faq has.

If you want a latest faq to be returned for each item, order by faq_id desc and group by item id. returns 5 rows with latest faq for each item

Comment: My goal is not the latest of anything.  I need the 5 FAQ's loaded into checkboxes that are checked if there is a relationship. Items and Faqs are many_to_many

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('faq')
->leftjoin('item_faq','faq.id','=','item_faq.faq_id')
->leftjoin('item','item_faq.item','=','item.id')
->select('faq.*','item.id as iId')->get();
```

Comment: This returned the same 9 items that exist on the join table, not the 5 items that exist on the FAQ table.

Comment: Of course because I didn't put any conditions it's up to you

Comment: I am trying to return the 5 items in the faq table, ordered by the join table order column and checked if there is a relationship.